# how to access vector in boost python

Tags: c++, vector, boost-python

I would like to access vector of c++ in python by using boost python. the vector is passed as argument in derived class function. But I am getting error. The example code is as

```
class Base
{
  public:
  virtual void Set(const std::vector<std::string>& AllParameters) = 0;
 };
class derived: public Base
{
  void Set(const std::vector<std::string>& AllParameters)
  {
     // some code here
  };


 main.cpp

 struct Basewrapper : Base, wrapper<Base>
 {
   void Set(const std::vector<std::string>& AllParameters)
  {
    this->get_override("Set")(AllParameters); 
  };

 BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(Example)
 {
    class_<Basewrapper , boost::noncopyable> ("Base")
    .def("Set",pure_virtual(&Base::Set))
    ;
  }
```

the problem is when i send list from python it is giving error did not match c++ signature.
thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

When I handled this kind of situation my usual method was that, since I am writing a Wrapper class for the binding anyway, I can create "proxy" functions that use python types.

boost does provide functions to do the conversions easily so you just use those from your proxy functions. To convert to an actual `std::vector` you will have to copy the data, of course. If the list can be very large and you don't want to do this, it's up to your C++ class to take some kind of abstract iterator.

In your case you can create a class called BaseProxy that has a pointer/reference/shared-ptr to a Base and has a method called Set (or that is called Set in your .def) that takes the boost python object and converts it to the vector then makes the appropriate call to your C++ object. In this case it returns void but if your C++ function returns something, you also return whatever is appropriate.